# Kotlin: Constructor when using parcelize

Tags: kotlin, constructor, parcelable

I am creating a small testapp to learn the kotlin way, but I have some problems with the Parcelable parameters.

I have created a abstract class:

```
abstract class Goal(var number: Int, var name: String) : Parcelable
```

Now I am trying to extend this class with a new class, but I have al sorts of construction problems:

```
@Parcelize
class OperationalGoal(number: Int, name: String, var description: String) : Goal(number, name)
```

**It is complaining about both `number` and `name`, that I need to add `val` or `var`. But I already defined the property inside my super class...**

Is there a way arround this?

Comment: Why you don't want to set them as var or val ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `@Parcelize` to work you need to `open` up the super's properties and override them in the child:

```
abstract class Goal(open var number: Int, open var name: String) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
class OperationalGoal(override var number: Int, override var name: String, var description: String) : Goal(number, name)
```